# SEGURIDAD/SERVIDORES: Guardar información en csv y protegerlo

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, csv, servlets

Actualmente, estoy trabajando con una empresa la cual tiene 2 formularios activos en su aplicación web de java.
La información se manda desde el form (.jsp) hacia un servlet creado (este recibe la información, la procesa y procede a crear un archivo csv con la información. Si el archivo existe, lo sobrescribe y continua en la siguiente línea)
El asunto es que cuando se guarda este archivo csv generado, se deposita en un lugar público. Si ingreso a la url del archivo puedo descargarlo tranquilamente, yo y cualquier persona.

Necesito generar una forma para que este archivo NO se pueda descargar, salvo que una persona se logue en un formulario simple (usser y pass). Esto porque la jefa de departamento necesita acceder de forma rápida y simple a este archivo.

Mi consulta aquí es:
¿Qué puedo implementar para lograr esta solución? No necesito una seguridad gigante, solo algo que permita que no se pueda descargar el archivo de forma publica, sino con algún metodo

Les dejo los codigos como los tengo
Formulario.jsp:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Formulario de Registro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="UneteServlet" method="post">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"><br>
        
        <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido"><br>
        
        <label for="celular">Celular:</label>
        <input type="text" id="celular" name="celular"><br>
        
        <label for="correo">Correo:</label>
        <input type="text" id="correo" name="correo"><br>
        
        <label for="oficina">Oficina:</label>
        <input type="text" id="oficina" name="oficina"><br>
        
        <label for="pregunta1">Pregunta 1:</label>
        <input type="text" id="pregunta1" name="pregunta1"><br>
        
        <label for="pregunta2">Pregunta 2:</label>
        <input type="text" id="pregunta2" name="pregunta2"><br>
        
        <label for="pregunta3">Pregunta 3:</label>
        <input type="text" id="pregunta3" name="pregunta3"><br>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet que se ocupa de la información solicitada:

```html
package mx.com.edge.PrudentialMexico.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/*import javax.jws.WebService;*/
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

//import com.opencsv.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServletLanding
 */

// @WebServlet(name = "ServletLanding", urlPatterns = { "/ServletLanding" })

public class UneteServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // (@see HttpServlet#HttpServlet();

    public UneteServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @param nextLine
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Start");
        //Fecha
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
        
        //Datos
        String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String apellidos = request.getParameter("apellido");
        String celular = request.getParameter("celular");
        String correo = request.getParameter("correo");
        String oficina = request.getParameter("oficina");
        String pregunta1 = request.getParameter("pregunta1");
        String pregunta2 = request.getParameter("pregunta2");
        String pregunta3 = request.getParameter("pregunta3");
        int correoHash = generateHash(correo);

        

        // Inicio TALENT LINK

        // CLOSE TALENT LINK

        CSVWriter writer = null;
        try {
            // location to write the CSV file
            String path = "c:\\assets\\files\\registroUnetePrueba.csv";
            FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter(path, true);

            writer = new com.opencsv.CSVWriter(outputfile);

            String[] L2 = { nombre, apellidos, celular, correo, oficina, pregunta1, pregunta2, pregunta3,
                     Integer.toString(correoHash), formattedDate };
            writer.writeNext(L2);
            System.out.println("Complete");

            writer.close();
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/gracias-unete");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    

    // Función para generar el hash
    private int generateHash(String string) {
        int hash = 0;

        if (string.length() == 0)
            return hash;

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            char c = string.charAt(i);
            hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + c;
            hash = hash & hash;
        }

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto  más que una pregunta de Java os SpringBoot, es de servidores y seguridad. Ahora mismo parece que desde el servlet estás abriendo/guardando el fichero en una carpeta dentro del árbol del servidor web, por lo que puede accederse online al poner la URL. Hay muchas maneras de hacer lo que quieres: moviendo el fichero fuera del directorio web y creando una página de lectura (protegida por contraseña a través de código), también podrías dejarlo en un directorio y usar configuración del servidor para prevenir acceso. Debes explorar qué opciones te convienen más.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Alvaro. Hice el ajuste en cuanto a la sección donde iria esta consulta.
Si, pues estuve pensando y creo que lo mejor es crear la pagina de lectura como tu dices